# JQuery Tabbed content - SEO friendly URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a jQuery based tabbed content, where clicking on tab changes the contents below, but I am having an issue from SEO point of view, I have been guided by the SEO person to make it SEO friendly and to make it SEO friendly I will have to pass the different urls on each tab.

Can somebody guide me how to pass the url on each time, for example

if clicked on Tab 2, then it should be http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/wzoBmy?Tab2

Title of the second tab added in the url with question mark

Here is the working demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjeevks121/pen/wzoBmy)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 })

})
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
 line-height: 1.6
}
.container {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
 background: none;
 color: #222;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
 background: #ededed;
 color: #222;
}
.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ededed;
 padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
 display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"> Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to detect # string from url using `window.location.hash.length` and parse hash string and using attribute selector you have to trigger click

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 });

  // this is code what you need
  if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
      var hash_str= window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
      $('.tab-link[data-tab=' + hash_str + ']').click();
       
   }

})
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 100px;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
 line-height: 1.6
}
.container {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
 background: none;
 color: #222;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
 background: #ededed;
 color: #222;
}
.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ededed;
 padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
 display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"> Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```